# Using li:first-child is grabbing all first-child li elements in a given class

Tags: html, css

I've got the following CSS below:

```
.last-ns li:first-child a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  height: 280px; 
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

In this example, the CSS is grabbing every single first-child `li` element in the class `.last-ns`. I do not want this. How can I tell the CSS to ignore all elements but the first `li` element in the class `.last-ns`.

I've tried several different things to complete failure.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.tree {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}

/* Connectors CSS */
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.tree li a {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

li a.just-line {
  display: none;
}

a.just-line + ul {
  padding-top: 74px;
}

a.just-line + ul:before {
  height: 74px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tree a {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
}

/* Accordion controls */

.ss_button { 
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ss_content {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.ss_content {
  display: none;
}

.tree li a:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* temporary solution */

.off-fix {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}

.off-fix2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}

/* Bottom row */

.stacked a {
  width: 100px;
}

.stacked li {
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  display: block;
}


/* PLAYGROUND - FIX AFTER */
.stacked li:last-child::before {
  border: 0 none;
}

.stacked li:after {
  border: 0 none;
}

/*::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.stacked li::before, .stacked li::after {
  border-top: 0 none;
}

.stacked li:after {
  border-left: 0 none;
}

/* Connectors CSS */
.stacked li:only-child::after, .stacked li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.stacked li:first-child::before, .stacked li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.stacked li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 0 none;
}

.last-ns ul:last-child::before {
  border-left: 0 none;
}

.last-ns ul:first-child li:first-child a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  height: 280px; 
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.last-ns ul li:first-child::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: -35px;
  height: 196px;
}

.drop-2 {
  margin-top: 216px;
}

.drop-1 {
  margin-top: 99px;
}

.drop-0 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.sm-title {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <title>Organization Chart</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel=
  'stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="mobile-css.css" media="screen and (max-width: 1023px)" rel=
  "stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="main.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"><!-- jQuery plugin -->

  <script src=
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script><!-- Custom scripts (accordion) -->

  <script src="app.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tree">
    <ul>
      <!-- DIRECTOR -->
      <li class="director">
        <a class="ss_button lvl-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class=
        "title">Director</span><br>
        <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
        <ul>
          <!-- ASSISTANT TO THE DIRECTOR -->
          <li>
            <a class="ss_button lvl-2" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class=
            "title">Assistant to the Director</span><br>
            <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
            <ul>
              <!-- DEPUTY DIRECTOR -->
              <li class="deputydirector">
                <a class="ss_button lvl-2" href=
                "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Deputy
                Director</span><br>
                <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <ul class='last-ns'>
                      <!-- ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR -->
                      <li class="associatedirector1 off-fix">
                        <a class="ss_button lvl-3" href=
                        "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Associate
                        Director</span><br>
                        <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <ul class='stacked drop-2'>
                                  <!-- CONSUMER LAWS & REGULATIONS -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                    "title">Consumer Laws &amp;
                                    Regulations</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li><!-- SENIOR ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR -->
                  <li class="seniorassociatedirector1">
                    <a class="ss_button lvl-3" href=
                    "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Senior Associate
                    Director</span><br>
                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <ul class='last-ns'>
                              <!-- ASSISTANT DIRECTOR -->
                              <li class="assistantdirector1 off-fix2">
                                <a class="ss_button lvl-4" href=
                                "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                "title">Assistant Director</span><br>
                                <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                                <ul class='stacked drop-1'>
                                  <!-- EXAMINER TRAINING -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title">Examiner
                                    Training</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li><!-- SUPERVISION ADMINISTRATION -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title">Supervision
                                    Administration</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li><!-- RESERVE BANK OVERSIGHT -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title">Reserve Bank
                                    Oversight</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <ul class='last-ns'>
                              <!-- ASSISTANT DIRECTOR -->
                              <li class="assistantdirector2 off-fix2">
                                <a class="ss_button lvl-4" href=
                                "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                "title">Assistant Director</span><br>
                                <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                                <ul class='stacked drop-1'>
                                  <!-- FAIR LENDING ENFORCEMENT -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title">Fair Lending
                                    Enforcement</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li>
                                  <!-- DECEPTIVE ACTS OR PRACTICES ENFORCEMENT -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title sm-title">Unfair &amp; Deceptive
                                    Acts or Practices Enforcement</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                                  </li><!-- SUPERVISORY POLICY & OUTREACH -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title">Supervisory Policy
                                    &amp; Outreach</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li><!-- APPLICATIONS -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);" class='ss_button lvl-6'>
                                    <span class="title">Applications</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li><!-- SENIOR ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR -->
                  <li class="seniorassociatedirector2">
                    <a class="ss_button lvl-3" href=
                    "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Senior Associate
                    Director</span><br>
                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <ul class='last-ns'>
                          <!-- DEPUTY ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR -->
                          <li class="depassociatedirector off-fix">
                            <a class="ss_button lvl-4" href=
                            "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Deputy
                            Associate Director</span><br>
                            <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                            <ul class='stacked drop-1'>
                              <!-- COMMUNITY DEVELOPMENT -->
                              <li>
                                <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                                   "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                                               "title">Community Development</span><br>
                                  <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                              </li><!-- POLICY ANALYSIS -->
                              <li>
                                <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                                   "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                                               "title">Policy Analysis</span><br>
                                  <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li><!-- ASSOCIATE DIRECTOR -->
                      <li class="associatedirector2">
                        <a class="ss_button lvl-4" href=
                        "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Associate
                        Director</span><br>
                        <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <ul class='last-ns'>
                              <!-- ASSISTANT DIRECTOR -->
                              <li class="assistantdirector3 off-fix">
                                <a class="ss_button lvl-5" href=
                                "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                "title">Assistant Director</span><br>
                                <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>

                                <ul class='stacked drop-0'>
                                  <!-- CONSUMER & COMMUNITY DEVELOPMENT RESEARCH -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                    "title sm-title">Consumer &amp; Community
                                    Development Research</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li><!-- INFORMATION MANAGEMENT -->
                                  <li>
                                    <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                                    "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                                    "title">Information Management</span><br>
                                    <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                                    Manager</span></a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <ul class='last-ns'>
                      <!-- ASSISTANT DIRECTOR -->
                      <li class="assistantdirector4 off-fix">
                        <a class="ss_button lvl-3" href=
                        "javascript:void(0);"><span class="title">Assistant
                        Director</span><br>
                        <span class="sm-hide">Person Name</span></a>
                        <ul class='stacked drop-2'>
                          <!-- ADMINISTRATION -->
                          <li>
                            <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                            "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                            "title">Administration</span><br>
                            <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                            Manager</span></a>
                          </li><!-- TECHNOLOGY DEPARTMENT -->
                          <li>
                            <a class='ss_button lvl-6' href=
                            "javascript:void(0);"><span class=
                            "title">Technology Development</span><br>
                            <span class="sm-hide">Person Name,
                            Manager</span></a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- End .tree -->
</body>
</html>
```

CodePen -- http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/zvgWjW?editors=110

Comment: It's the normal behavior. You can add another class on the first .last-ns element and use .last-ns.you-new-class li:first-child

Comment: `.last-ns` *is* a `ul`. Selecting `ul` after it will do you no good.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud I tried your method but nothing happens. `.last-ns` is my parent `ul` element which has a `li` of other `ul` elements with `li` elements. I want only the first `li` element from the `.last-ns` parent.

Comment: @Krii You're right. That was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I've read your markup a little too fast ;) Krii has posted the right answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.last-ns > li:first-child > a::before`. See [the css selector reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

The `>` selector selects only the direct child of the specified parent.

Comment: When I change it to `.last-ns > li:first-child a` it selects all `a` elements within my `.last-ns` class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `>` CSS selector. If you have a selector `.Foo > .Bar`, it will only apply that style to elements that are direct children of `.Foo` that have the `.Bar` class.

### Example

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar" id="first">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo > .bar
{
    background: red;
}
```

In this example, the element with the `#first` id will be the only element that will have the `background: red` style.

Comment: I've altered the code to `.last-ns > li:first-child a { background: red; }` and still all my `a` elements within my `.last-ns` class get changed.

Comment: A Krii explained, I can use that `>` selector more than once. SO my solution became `.last-ns > li:first-child > a { background: red; }`. Thank you for your help.